# How can you use databases to create a search scroll of pictures on a database?

Tags: database, image, scroll

I am creating an online store, in order for the customer to purchase an item, they need to click on a category and therefore view all products under that specified category. I am looking for a delphi code that will help me create a search scroll using products saved on database format

I tried using timages but I could not automatically update the product list using delphi code, but had top manualy add the picture of the product manually.